# Handling cleaning up on process termination

Tags: .net, winforms

Am curious.. whether can i handle the cleaning up of an object.
If i kill my application from Task Manager.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Application being shutdown from Task Manager","Caution",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            do{}while(true);
        }
    }
```

This method works if i end my application from the TASK MANAGER. But i want to know whether a similar handling is possible if i end my application by killing the process under which my application is running

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your process can't get any notifications when it's killed, because that would defeat the purpose of having forced process termination (as opposed to asking it to terminate). The OS releases most resources for you, so you shouldn't have any resources that *need* manual cleanup - what if the computer BSODs or I pull out the power cord?